# Why is Home using so much battery life?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, power-management, homekit

[image: grab]
I don’t use Home to control my lights. I use the Hue app. Why is it using so much power in the background? I’m on iOS 15.1.1 on an iPhone 12 mini.

Comment: On my iPhone 12 mini (iOS 15.2), Home does not even appear in the list. Try to upgrade to iOS 15.2. or maybe you have changed some default settings related to Home.